# Get interests of facebook page followers

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to know if it's possible to get Facebook Page Followers interests? Or other insights of the followers with fb graph api.

For a user it's possible to get likes as follow:

```
/me/likes?fields=app_id,category,name,fan_count
```

And you can get page post impressions of a page:
I know how to get the page post impressions

```
page_id/insights/page_posts_impressions/?period=days_28
```

But I need the insights of followers of a page. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Not directly possible. You'd have to get the users to authenticate your Facebook app before you can get any information about them.

Comment: So information/insights from followers is impossible?Only of authenticated users?

Comment: Yeah. It's a privacy issue if you think about it. I'll follow a page, but it doesn't explicitly ask me permissions for my information, and I wouldn't want it to. Just because I follow a page doesn't give it free reign to my personal information.